# Dúvida sobre como chamar a função com cada botão de mouse

Tags: javascript

Pessoal tenho esse código mas não consigo fazer com que cada botão do mouse chame uma função diferente:

```
var tela = document.getElementById("tela");
var c = tela.getContext("2d");

c.strokeStyle = "black";
c.strokeRect(0, 0, 600, 400);

var atira = function(evento) {
    var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
    var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;

    c.fillStyle = "blue";
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    c.fill();
};

var atira2 = function(evento) {
    var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
    var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;

    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    c.fill();
};

tela.onclick = function(evento) {
    switch(evento.which) {
        case 1 :
            console.log("botao esquerdo");
            tela.onclick = atira;
            break;
        case 2 :
            console.log("botao do meio");
            tela.onclick = atira2;
            break;
        case 3 :
            console.log("botao direito");
        default:
            console.log("mouse estranho");
    }
};
```

Comment: Pode por também seu html? pode ser só a parte relevante.

Answer (score 3):

Para ouvir os seus botões, utilize [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown).

Veja:

```
document.getElementById('workspace').addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if(3 === event.which) alert('right click!');
  else alert('left click!');
}, false);
```

Para ressaltar, `workspace` é o `id` do elemento onde o usuário vai clicar e que você deseja ouvir o pressionamento do botão.

Um exemplo completo, [veja aqui, no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/7pHSP/).

---

No seu caso em específico, você não precisa do `tela.onclick` para engatilhar as suas funções. Veja um exemplo que criei (<sup>você precisa *remover* os comentários em questão para funcionar</sup>) baseado no seu cenário:

```
var tela = document.getElementById("tela");

/* 
 * var c = tela.getContext("2d");
 * c.strokeStyle = "black";
 * c.strokeRect(0, 0, 600, 400); 
 */

var atira = function(evento) {
  var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
  var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;

  c.fillStyle = "blue";
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  c.fill();
};

var atira2 = function(evento) {
  var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
  var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;

  c.fillStyle = "red";
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  c.fill();
};

tela.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evento) {
  if(1 === evento.which) {
      console.log('botão esquerdo');
      atira();
  } else if(3 === evento.which) {
      console.log('botão direito'); 
      atira2();
  }
}, false);

tela.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

O exemplo completo [está aqui, no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/Mn24M/).

---

*<sub>Se nenhum dos exemplos funcionar para você, o problema **pode** estar no seu DOM. Por favor, poste o seu HTML.</sub>*

*<sub>Se você não entendeu o porquê d'eu estar utilizando `.addEventListener`, [veja a documentação aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).</sub>*

Comment: *Yoda conditions*!

Comment: Não consigo não usar, @Beterraba. UAhuahua

Comment: O autor da pergunta relatou ter tentado isso e obtido o seguinte erro: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined*. (Excluí a postagem dele pois foi postada como resposta).

Comment: Oi @bfavaretto. Então, ele deu CTRL+C / CTRL+V no meu código e essa reação é mais do que normal – é esperada. Como pode ver no código e inclusive na advertência da minha postagem, existem três linhas que eu comentei no código dele para que eu pudesse exemplificar melhor – linhas essas que caso ausentes resultam no tal erro pelo usuário apresentado. Portanto, cabe a ele descomentar as linhas e fazer as alterações que propus no(s) meu(s) exemplo(s).

Answer (score 2):

O seu `tela.onclick` está simplesmente redefinido a si mesmo durante o primeiro clique, de modo que todo clique subsequente executará a mesma função toda vez. Exemplo:

```
// O mouse foi clicado com o botão esquerdo
tela.onclick = function(evento) {
    switch(evento.which) {
        case 1 :                           // Entrou aqui...
            console.log("botao esquerdo");
            tela.onclick = atira;          // Aqui você redefiniu tela.onclick...
            break;                         // Saiu..
    }
    // ...e não fez mais nada! o primeiro clique não disparou nenhuma função (pun intended).
}; 
// O mouse foi clicado de novo com o botão esquerdo
tela.onclick = atira; // Ele vai executar o código de atira. Parece que funcionou, não? Só que...
// O mouse foi clicado de novo, agora com o botão direito
tela.onclick = atira; // Ele vai executar o código de atira, não de atira3...
```

Em vez de redefinir o `tela.onclick`, simplesmente chame a função relevante:

```
tela.onclick = function(evento) {
    switch(evento.which) {
        case 1 :
            console.log("botao esquerdo");
            atira();
            break;
        case 2 :
            console.log("botao do meio");
            atira2();
            break;
        case 3 :
            console.log("botao direito");
            ...
        default:
            console.log("mouse estranho");
    }
};
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema imediato (de todos os cliques estarem indo pra mesma função). Para uma solução mais completa, ver a [resposta do Guilherme Oderdenge](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27090/215).

Answer (score 1):

Também estava tentando resolver este mesmo exercício, e consegui da seguinte forma:

```
tela.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evento){

switch(evento.which){

    case 1:
        console.log("botão esquerdo");
        tela.onclick = atira; 
        break;

    case 3:
        console.log("botão direito");
        tela.oncontextmenu = atira2;
        break;

    default:
        console.log("mouse estranho");  

  }
}, false);
```

as respostas postadas aqui me ajudaram em alguns pontos, mas o que me permitiu "matar a charada" foi o entendimento de que o evento CLICK está vinculado ao botão esquerdo do mouse e o evento CONTEXTMENU é que está vinculado ao botão direito do mouse.

Segue material que me ajudou: [eventos em Javascript](http://www.tutsup.com/2014/04/25/eventos-em-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

Olha, uma maneira simples de executar funções para cada click do mouse, esquerdo e direito, é desabilitar a função responsável pelo menu do click direito e substituir por outra, veja se entende:

```
<canvas id = "tela" width = "800" height = "800"> </canvas>

<script>

var tela = document.getElementById("tela");
var c = tela.getContext("2d");

c.fillStyle = "gray";
c.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

var fazCirculoAzul = function(x, y){
    c.fillStyle = "blue";
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    c.fill();
}

var fazCirculoVermelho = function(x, y){
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    c.fill();
}

tela.onclick = function(evento){

    var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
    var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;

    fazCirculoAzul(x, y);
}

tela.oncontextmenu = function(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
    var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;

    fazCirculoVermelho(x, y);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Os navegadores entendem que o onclick é apenas para cliques do botão esquerdo! Note que, quando você clica com o botão direito, uma janelinha com o menu de ações é aberto. A função que cuida disso é a do oncontextmenu e, para impedir o navegador de abrir a janelinha de menu, você ainda pode adicionar a chamada a evento.preventDefault():

```js
<canvas id="tela" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
 var tela = document.getElementById("tela");
 var c = tela.getContext("2d");

 c.fillStyle="gray";
 c.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 400);


 var atiraVermelho = function(evento) {
  var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
  var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;

  c.fillStyle="red";
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2*3.14);
  c.fill();
 };

 var atiraAzul = function(evento) {
  var x = evento.pageX - tela.offsetLeft;
  var y = evento.pageY - tela.offsetTop;

  c.fillStyle="blue";
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2*3.14);
  c.fill();

  evento.preventDefault();
 };

 tela.onclick = atiraVermelho;
 tela.oncontextmenu = atiraAzul;

</script>
```